# token must be bytes, 'List' is not callable? P3.7

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, authentication, mysql-connector

I'm trying to verify the password input of user with the password (encrypted) in MySQLdb:
Working with mysqlconnector, python 3.7

encryptor.py :
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

```
#---key-----



key = b'Ys_G_ziOS1AFs6X-jD3rtgsh77b3HpF7A-yiGpH-5Fg='
cipher_suite = Fernet(key)
cipher_text = cipher_suite.encrypt(b"password")  # Convert in byte
print(cipher_text)




key1 = b'Ys_G_ziOS1AFs6X-jD3rtgsh77b3HpF7A-yiGpH-5Fg='
cipher_suite1 = Fernet(key1)
chiper_text1 = b'gAAAAABcHA2-58GwFxKzMzZRJsNV269_Nc-xvabFJcXV8yf0BuKI2XtD7211Vusf_hMXNrvK0glamHuoJhwPegP9iFRjXpANcg=='



unciphered_text = (cipher_suite1.decrypt(chiper_text1))

print(unciphered_text)
```

now the form is a simple `<form method='POST' action='cgi-bin/file.py'>`

with username, name = username , password, name=password

```
import mysql.connector
from config import *
from encryptor import *
import cgi, cgitb
import os


#----user/pasw params

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
username1 = form.getvalue('username')
password1 = form.getvalue('password')
print(f"Username: {username1}  Password: {password1}")


#Search password in DB

mycursor = mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute("USE continental")
sql_password = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE username ='root'"
#assword23 = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE user = %s", (username1,)
mycursor.execute(sql_password)



find_password = mycursor.fetchall()    # ????


 unciphered_text1 = (cipher_suite1.decrypt(find_password))#error


if password1==unciphered_text1:
    print("ok")
else:
    print(unciphered_text1)

   unciphered_text1 = (cipher_suite1.decrypt(find_password))
  File "/Users/jhon/prova/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cryptography/fernet.py", line 74, in decrypt
    timestamp, data = Fernet._get_unverified_token_data(token)
  File "/Users/jhon/prova/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cryptography/fernet.py", line 86, in _get_unverified_token_data
    raise TypeError("token must be bytes.")
TypeError: token must be bytes.

 token must be bytes.
```

I tried to convert without success, the idea was confront the input password with decrypted password from database, because the method for encrypt generates a different hash every time.
I have no idea how to fix
I can not correct the error, the fetchall () should return a list that I should put in bytes, otherwise the method of decrypt does not work in this way, or maybe read only strings in bytes (cipher_text), I can not understand.
Thanks to all.